# For what values of x does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {kn \choose ln}x^n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having some hard time answering the following question:

For what values of $x\in \Bbb{R}$ does this series converge

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {kn \choose ln}x^n$

where $k>l$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test says $$\left|\frac{(kn+1)..(kn+k)}{(mn+1)..(mn+m)(ln+1)...(ln+l)}x\right|<1$$
where $m=k-l$.  Take out factors of $n$ top and bottom, and let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: OK, thank you! but what happens if this expression equals 1? than the ratio test won't help me

Comment: It ends up $|Cx|<1$.  That gives the interval from $-1/C$ to $1/C$, whether $C=1$ or not.  It is only at the very edge, that is $x=\pm1/C$, the ratio test always fails.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ratio test:

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\binom{k(n+1)}{\ell(n+1)}x^{n+1}}{\binom{kn}{\ell n}x^n}\right|&=\frac{(kn+k)!(\ell n)!\big((k-\ell)n\big)!}{(\ell n+\ell)!\big((k-\ell)n+(k-\ell)\big)!(kn)!}|x|\\\\
&=\frac{(kn+k)^{\underline k}}{(\ell n+\ell)^{\underline \ell}\big((k-\ell)n+(k-\ell)\big)^{\underline{k-\ell}}}|x|\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $a^{\underline k}=a(a-1)(a-2)\ldots(a-k+1)$ is the [falling factorial](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer-Symbol). Then observe that numerator and denominator of the fraction are both polynomials in $n$ of degree $k$.